# send image from external computer a to external computer b Client/Server

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i want to make two application client and server in differents computers (home and work) differents ip adresses with function

```
stream
```

and

```
listen
```

how can send this image between two external ip ??

or is there any ohter ways to do this ?

note : i will make function to get the current ip from the server

thanks best regards

Answer (score 0):

A. It will have to be a service running on port 80 or 443, and preferably using HTTP. Otherwise your network admins will most likely block your connection.

B. Do you need to stream or send snapshots?

Comment: [Check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx)